# Stretch OpenGL texture to window dimensions

Tags: opengl, video, render, draw, rgb

I have a function that renders RGB video frames to a window. This works fine for the captured dimensions (640 x 480) if the window is the same dimensions but when I resize the window the rendering is not correct:

[img http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/1694/screenshot20120404at536.png](http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/1694/screenshot20120404at536.png)

Edit: The now working function.

```
static inline void draw_rgb(
     unsigned char * buf, unsigned x, unsigned y, unsigned window_width,
     unsigned window_height, unsigned frame_width, unsigned frame_height
 )
{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, 1);

    glTextureRangeAPPLE(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, window_width * window_height * 2, buf);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, 0, GL_RGBA, frame_width, frame_height, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV, buf);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glViewport(x, y, window_width, window_height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glOrtho((GLfloat)0, (GLfloat)window_width, (GLfloat)0, (GLfloat)window_height, -1.0, 1.0);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    {
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex2f(0.0f, window_height);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, frame_height);
        glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(frame_width, frame_height);
        glVertex2f(window_width, 0.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(frame_width, 0.0f);
        glVertex2f(window_width, window_height);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

Comment: Why choose `EXT_texture_rectangle`/`ARB_texture_rectangle` over `ARB_texture_non_power_of_two`?

Comment: The image becomes distorted as shown here: [link](http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/1694/screenshot20120404at536.png)

Comment: I should have mentioned I am an OpenGL newbie.

Comment: @genpfault: Because they're more widely supported, and have non-normalized texture coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a combination of two factors.

First, as datenwolf pointed out, your texture's width/height is constant. It doesn't change when the window's size does. BTW, you shouldn't be rebuilding the texture every frame unless the texture's data changes. And even then, you can upload changes with [`glTexSubImage2D`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glTexSubImage2D) rather than `glTexImage`. You don't need to call the `glTexParameter` stuff either.

Second, this also means that your *texture coordinates* don't change. So you need to change your quad drawing to be this:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
{
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, window_height);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, texture_height);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(texture_width, texture_height);
    glVertex2f(window_width, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(texture_width, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(window_width, window_height);
}
glEnd();
```

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is here

> ```
> glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, 0, GL_RGBA, window_width, window_height, 0,
>          GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV, buf);
> ```

glTexImage takes the size of your texture data, not the window size or the size of the desired output.

Comment: If I give it the size of the texture data (640 x 480) the rendered frames are no longer distorted but instead clipped to the window size.

Comment: @junglecat: Well, you determine the output size using the projection and the vertex positions of the textured quads. Adjust those.

Answer (score 0):

Your `glViewport` call is using the same `w` and `h` variables that represent the size of the texture everywhere else.

Try changing the `glViewport` to use the size of the window you're rendering into, instead of `w` and `h`.  Everything else should be able to stay the same.

For better results, you could adapt the viewport size to maintain the aspect ratio of your video, by reducing the viewport's width or height so that the video doesn't look stretched.

Comment: @junglecat: You kinda missed the point. Your texture is not the same size as your window. If it were, then you wouldn't need to *stretch* it. That's where your corruption is coming from: your texture's size is *fixed*; it's the window's size that changes.